# getStaticPaths not creating paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have `data` folder that contains `events.ts`:

```js
export const EventsData: Event[] = [
  {
    name: 'School-Uniform-Distribution',
    images: ['/community/conferences/react-foo.png', "/community/conferences/react-foo.png"],
  },
  {
    name: 'College-Uniform',
    images: ['/community/conferences/react-foo.png', "/community/conferences/react-foo.png"],
  },
];
```

type `Event` is:

```
export type Event = {
  name: string;
  images: string[];
};
```

I have the `getStaticPath` and `getStaticProps` methods in `pages/our-contribution/[pid].tsx` :

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<Props> = async (context) => {
  const event = EventsData;
  console.log(event, "event")
  return {
    props: { event: event },
  };
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = EventsData.map(event => ({
      params: {pid: event.name},
  }));
  console.log(paths, "paths")
  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  return {paths, fallback: false}
}
```

I get this error:
[image]

Can you help me, please ?

Update:
This is the error trace for one route:
[image]

`pages/our-contribution/[pid].tsx`:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';

import { Event } from 'types/event';
import {EventsData} from 'data/events';

type Props = {
  event: Event[];
};

const Event = ({event} : Props) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  return <p>Event: {event}</p>
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<Props> = async (context) => {
  const event = EventsData;
  console.log(event, "event")
  return {
    props: { event: event },
  };
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = EventsData.map(event => ({
      params: {pid: event.name},
  }));
  console.log(paths, "paths")
  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  return {paths, fallback: false}
}

export default Event
```

Comment: Can you also show the React code that you have for that page?

Comment: Nothing much, just a line. Added in the question, @juliomalves

Comment: `event` is an array of objects, you can't just render that in JSX. Either map through the array and render appropriate JSX elements, or convert it to a string with `JSON.stringify(event)`.

Comment: @juliomalves Now, I get different error saying `A required parameter (pid) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /our-contribution/[pid]`

Comment: Is the `EventsData` array you provided the same you're using in your code? If all the objects in that array have a valid string for the `name` field then that error shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of errors in the code.
One error that block your build is

```js
const Event = ({event} : Props) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  return <p>Event: {event}</p>
}
```

You can't directly print an object or array in tsx, you should convert the object first into string if you are trying to debug it. Something like:

```
  return <p>Event: {event.toString()}</p>
```

Then a i notice something strange in your variables name `event` props looks like a single event but instead you give an array of events i don't know if it is correct but maybe it should be like this:

```
type Props = {
  event: Event;
};
```

or it should be named:

```
type Props = {
  events: Event[];
};
```